# passing movable object by value to NOT operator overloading

Tags: c++, move-semantics, pass-by-value

What's wrong here?

```
class A {
  A(const A&); //no copy constructor
  A& operator= (const A&); //no copy assignment
public:
  bool x;
  A(bool _x):x(_x){}
  A(A&& a):x(a.x); //move constructor
  A& operator= (A&& a){x = a.x; return *this;} //move assignment
};
A operator&& (A a, A b) {return A(a.x && b.x);} //this works

A operator! (A&& a) {return A(!(a.x));} //this also works

//but if instead I use 
A operator! (A a) {return A(!(a.x));} 
//it leads to linker error for missing copy constructor.
```

Well, of course I can pass argument by r-reference. It does not make much sense to pass-by-value objects that are known to be non-copyable. But still, why passing by value works with "&&" and fails with "!"?

Edit: I found that error occures only when I use this operator in a following way:

```
A f(bool x) {return A(x);}
std::vector<A> v;
v.push_back(!f(true));
```

If I remove "!" from last line, it compiles.
Does standard says something about it? Maybe it's just my old MSVC2010 compiler problem?

Comment: How do you define works? You can't use this `operator&&` without getting a compiler error. [link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fKkForUvDPI9FPxO)

Comment: by your link it works with A a(true), b(true); std::move(a)&&std::move(b);

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code. How are you calling `operator!` and with what argument?

Comment: Compiles fine using `!std::move(a)` on Gcc 6.2 (given the typo in your move ctor is fixed).

Comment: I have a function `A f();`, `vector<A> v` and use it in ways like `v.push_back(!f());`

Comment: @DmitryJ Well [**this**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55d3b94812f474ae) works.

Comment: I'm using VC2013 and it initially gives "error C2593: 'operator !' is ambiguous" but builds when `A operator! (A&& a) { return A(!(a.x)); }` is commented out.

Comment: Ok, then maybe it is just MSVC2010 does not apply move semantics somewhere in this chain. After all, it does not fully support c++0x. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I just tried with VS 2010, and it worked.  The move constructor was missing a body, though (it ended in `;` instead of `{}`), so I had to fix that first, and `operator!()` was ambiguous with both versions uncommented, but if I commented out one `operator!()` and left the other, it compiled fine regardless of which operator I commented out.  Perhaps the error is actually being caused by something else.  I was testing with [the code you provided](http://ideone.com/n8uEzD).